# Register page has login form also, getting InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My page has 2 forms on it, form #1 is generated using:

```
<%= form_for (@user) .... %>
```

The 2nd form on the page for login is done manually:

```
<form ...>
</form>
```

When I try and login using form #2, I get:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

My application_controller has:

```
protect_from_forgery
```

Looking at the html I see:

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/> 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="xxxxx="/>
```

(I changed the token for this post to xxxx..)

Not sure what the issue is?  Is 2 forms on a page not allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forms_for` automatically includes a hidden input with the authenticity token so it is submitted with the form. You need to do that with your manually created form, too.

Add the following tag helper to your form:

```
hidden_field_tag request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, form_authenticity_token
```

Comment: i see, so all forms HAVE to use form_for then since I have protected_from_forgery?   how can I replicate, I have to generate the token somehow on the manual form that I create..hmmm...

Comment: Ummm, no you can't do that the authenticity token is not static. If you hard-code it, it will still be invalid. If it was static it wouldn't offer any protection!

Comment: You can access the authenticity token in your view by using <%= form_authenticity_token %>

Answer (score 2):

You need to either use the [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) or [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) helper. An authenticity token is automatically generated and added to the HTML, and allows [Rails to help prevent](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) against [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csrf).

When you don't use the form helpers, the authenticity is not included in the generated HTML and thus not in the form's submission. This causes Rails to believe the request has been forged and is an attempt at attacking the application.